# How to animate Button below AnimatedList when inserting items?

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have a system that includes a AnimatedList that adds a set amount of items on each click, and a button that does that operation below it
I made it so that each item will be added with a small delay to make it look better but everytime an item is added, the button below the animated List translated down instantly, which is not what I want.

I want to make it so that the button will go down smoothly while the items in the animatedList slides in.

code:

```
Widget createExpandList() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: AnimatedList(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            key: animatedListKey,
            initialItemCount: widget.rowDisplay,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index, animation) {
              return SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset(0, 0))
                    .animate(CurvedAnimation(
                        parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeInOut)),
                child: Card(
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), child: dataList[index])),
              );
            }),
          ),
          //add button
        ), //the next/back button, only appears when data rows exceed row display
        dataList.length > widget.rowDisplay
            ? Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
                        overlayColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue[800])),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //add to animated list
                      //check if it is last page
                      if (lastPage) {
                        return null;
                      }

                      page++;
                      if (page * widget.rowDisplay > dataList.length) {
                        lastPage = true;
                        for (int i = 0;
                            i < dataList.length.remainder(widget.rowDisplay);
                            i++) {
                          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100 + i * 100))
                              .then((value) => animatedListKey.currentState!
                                  .insertItem(
                                      i + ((page - 1) * widget.rowDisplay),
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400)));
                        }
                      } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < widget.rowDisplay; i++) {
                          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100 + i * 100))
                              .then((value) => animatedListKey.currentState!
                                  .insertItem(
                                      i + ((page - 1) * widget.rowDisplay),
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400)));
                        }
                      }

                      //doesnt allow it to go past the last page
                      if (lastPage) {
                        return null;
                      } else {
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ])
            : Container()
      ],
    );
  }
```

any help would be appreciated.

What it looks like now: (I want the button to go down smoothly)

[image: DEMO: animatedList button translation]